# get the amount of rows in a table

Tags: javascript, dalekjs

I want to get the amount of rows in a table on my page.
I am trying to do this using .execute(function(){}) but how is it possible to get a variable out of the execute function and use it there. 
this isn't the counter yet, buy i can't even get a variable to work.
i tried something like this:

```
.execute(function(){
    global.amountOfRows = 5;
})

.assert.numberOfElements('#content-list > tbody > tr', global.amountOfRows)
```

i tried the same using `var amountOfRows = 5;`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery to return the number of row in your table body

```
$('#your_table_id tbody').find('tr').length;
http://api.jquery.com/length/
```

I tried this but it didnt work out as planned.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery to return the number of row in your table body

```
$('#your_table_id tbody').find('tr').length;
```

http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: but how can i get this variable to work outside of the .execute?
So i'm making a variable inside .execute, and want to use it outside of it.

Comment: Why are you even using .execute? Anyway for the variable to work outside, you can just declare it outside .execute and set it inside .execute.

Comment: well i'm trying it with .execute because my test is around 1000 lines, and a lot of functions and .done(). When i want to declare a variable for the entire test that is no problem, but using it on 1 of the 50 pages i go through isn't possible at the moment for me because i can't use jquery outside of module.exports{} as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately Dalek doesn't has the capability to do assertions on data you did get out of a `execute` statement at the moment, but there is a workaround for you ;)

```
.execute(function(){
    // store as a `data` var
    this.data('amountOfRows', 5);
})
// doSomeOtherStuff
.execute(function () {
  // using jquery here to keep it short
  var actualNumberOfRows = $(''#content-list > tbody > tr').length;
  // do an "in browser" assertion
  this.assert.ok((actualNumberOfRows === this.data('amountOfRows')), 'Amount of rows is as expected');
})
.done();
```

You can find further info on this undocumented API here:
https://github.com/asciidisco/jsdays-workshop/blob/5-js/test/dalek/javascript.js#L16-L29

Comment: well that's one nice piece of art you got here. I tried to make it my own but it didn't work out that well. I want to get the amount of rows  and use this is another test. I can't get this to work. Have you maybe got another idea on how to fix that? This already helps me a lot ! ---- For example, in the link you gave me: I want to get the amount of rows in 'Can execute a JS event' and use it in 'Can move data around'

Comment: It should be persisted during a complete test run. So maybe something is wrong with your tests...
Can you give me a stripped down version in a gist, or so?!

Comment: i'm sorry, i found out why it didn't work for me. it works fine now, thanks for your help!